# What is the time complexity of Python List Reverse?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I have seen this page  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity  but I don't see the `reverse()` function in there for lists.  What is the time time complexity of `list`'s `reverse()`?

My experiments with time indicate that it is `O(n)` for larger sizes. Can anyone confirm it ?

timeit Time to reverse a list of size

```
   10    .1027
  100    .2347
 1000    .6704
10000   6.204
20000  12.9
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it is O(n) where n - length of list.
Look here for more information: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Answer (score 32):

If you look into the implementation of the `reverse` method [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Objects/listobject.c), then it looks as follows:

```
static PyObject *
listreverse(PyListObject *self)
{
    if (Py_SIZE(self) > 1)
        reverse_slice(self->ob_item, self->ob_item + Py_SIZE(self));
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

So, the operation is actually delegated to `reverse_slice`. Then, let's look into it:

```
static void
reverse_slice(PyObject **lo, PyObject **hi)
{
    assert(lo && hi);

    --hi;
    while (lo < hi) {
        PyObject *t = *lo;
        *lo = *hi;
        *hi = t;
        ++lo;
        --hi;
    }
}
```

So, here are 2 indices initially set at the start and end of the list. Then, at each iteration of `while` loop, elements at respective indices are swapped:

```
PyObject *t = *lo;
*lo = *hi;
*hi = t;
```

And then the left index gets incremented and the right one decremented:

```
++lo;
--hi;
```

The loop goes on as long as the right index exceeds the left one. So, if there're `n` elements in the list, then there will be performed `n/2` iterations and hence the time complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: I know that this is not the top answer, but this is by far the most thorough. How did you look at the implementation of the function?

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude Back then I looked into https://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Objects/listobject.c. Additionally, you may look into https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/6405feecda6a5d5dd7a4240eb3054a2676ed29b1 on github. I also updated the answer specifying the source file.

Answer (score 4):

Reversing a list either through an in-built library like reverse() or by using slicing a=a[::--] both are going to take the same amount of time i.e O(n)

Answer (score 3):

If you see the algorithm is easy to view that the time complexity of reverse is `O(n)` (***linear time complexity***) where **n** is the number of the element in the list.